# Unable to disable long click on an editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, onlongclicklistener

I have an EditText on which I need to disable long click. On long clicking the editText the action mode set for the apps WebView pops up.

Tried adding the below code but failed.

```
editTextView.setLongClickable(false);
editTextView.setTextIsSelectable(false);
```

Also tried adding

```
longClickable="false"
```

on the layout xml.

Comment: post your layout file

Comment: Did you try using view.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about you, but a simple `editText.setLongClickable(false);` works as expected.

You may have some other method or xml overriding it, for example:

```
    // example 1
    editText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    editText.setLongClickable(false);
```

is not the same as:

```
    // example 2
    editText.setLongClickable(false);
    editText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

In example 1, editText's long-click will be disabled.

In example 2, editText's long-click is still enabled.

These are just java examples, there can also be xml elements to check for.

You need to check your flow or post more code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
editTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

**OR**

```
editTextView.setClickable(false);
editTextView.setFocusable(false);
```